# Druid Deployment with Minio and PostgreSQL in Minikube

Tags: java, minikube, minio, druid

I'm trying to deploy Druid in Minikube with Minio and PostgrSQL.
I'm using Druid-Opearor and all druid-sds-cluster-brokers-0, druid-sds-cluster-coordinators-0,druid-sds-cluster-historicals-0, druid-sds-cluster-middlemanagers-0, druid-sds-cluster-routers-0 are stateful set. Its having status 1/1 and on port-forwarding I'm getting Druid Console.
In druid console when I tried loading example data-source and the after few seconds the task goes to failed state. On checking the status of task from console it mentioned like this `errorMsg": "Task execution process exited unsuccessfully with code[137]. See middleManager logs for more details..."` and on checking logs it says `Request failed with status code 404`

Will add the minio and psotgresql configuration below :

```
    s3service.s3-endpoint=192.168.59.xxx
    s3service.s3-endpoint-http-port=30000
    s3service.disable-dns-buckets=true
    s3service.https-only=false
```

```
    druid.metadata.storage.type=postgresql
    druid.metadata.storage.connector.connectURI=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-service.dev.svc.cluster.local:5432/druid_db
    druid.metadata.storage.connector.host=postgres-service.dev.svc.cluster.local
    druid.metadata.storage.connector.port=5432
    druid.metadata.storage.connector.user=postgres
    druid.metadata.storage.connector.password=test
    # druid.metadata.storage.connector.database=druid_db
    druid.metadata.storage.connector.createTables=true
```

```
    druid.storage.type=s3
    druid.storage.bucket=test-bucket
    druid.storage.baseKey=druid/segments-test-dev
    druid.s3.accessKey=xxxxxxxxxxxx
    druid.s3.secretKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    druid.s3.protocol=http
    druid.s3.enabePathStyleAccess=true
    druid.s3.region=us-east-1
    druid.s3.endpoint.signingRegion=us-east-1
    druid.s3.endpoint.url=http://192.168.59.xxx:30000/
```

I tried increasing the memory of Minikube to 8GB still no luck. I tried adding request and limit to middlemanager as

```
 resources:
        limits:
          cpu: "1"
          memory: 1Gi
        requests:
          cpu: "1"
          memory: 1Gi
```

But still the task is getting failed. I don't know what the issue. Looking for some insights or help. Thanks

Comment: Have you set the javaOptsArray property in the middle manager config? Middle Manager will spawn Peon JVMs for individual tasks. The javaOptsArray specifies heap and off-heap memory available to each Peon. Some docs: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration/#middlemanager-configuration

Comment: Also, although not exactly the same because this uses helm charts, here is a minikube deployment of Druid blog: https://imply.io/blog/apache-druid-for-preppers/